# Setting Cron Expression for Jenkins Pipeline via Script

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to run my Jenkins multibranch pipeline regulary during a week. Therefore I tried to set the Cron property for my pipeline directly in the `Jenkinsfile` as follows:

```
@Library('pipelines@master) _
properties([pipelineTriggers([cron('*/5 * * * *')])])
runPipeline()
```

In can see in the output of the build, that the properties step has been executed, but the pipeline does not start automatically.

Did I configure the Cron trigger correctly? How can I check if the trigger has been configured?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cron trigger in declarative way like below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers{
        cron('*/5 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage ("Test Stage1"){
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Hello Test Stage1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Test Stage2"){
            steps{
                echo "Hello Test Stage2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```